# Basic oracle procedure doesn't run

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a very simple procedure in oracle sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE function_name
IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Test');
END;

function_name();
```

This doesn't run and gives the following error:

```
8/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FUNCTION_NAME" 
9/0       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query    json_object json_array
```

Comment: You need a `/` on a line on its own to mark the end of the procedure. (A procedure called 'function_name' is a bit confusing...). The call then needs to be an another PL/SQL block, which can be int he same script, depending on your client.

Comment: @AlexPoole Ah I see, don't worry the name is just a placeholder. I'm not sure what you mean by PL/SQL block though, could you explain further? I'm using Oracle Sql developer

Comment: You can't just call `function_name();` from SQL. You could use an anonymous PL/SQL block for testing, i.e. `begin function_name; end;` (followed by another `/`). Or SQL Developer has tools to let you run procedures; or you can `exec function_name;` in your worksheet.

Comment: _"I'm not sure what you mean by PL/SQL block"_   Sounds like you need to spend some quality time with the docs.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/overview.html#GUID-826B070B-4888-4398-889B-61A3C6B91349